# Using Lucene.Net with the Repository pattern?

Tags: lucene.net

Anybody doing this? I am curious to know if anyone has implemented this in their own projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I have found that there is not a lot of good information out there about this. I am implementing my own LuceneContext that can be used like a Unit Of Work for a repository.